# Use awk to compare two files based on one column

Tags: linux, awk

I have two files which look like this:

file 1:

```
abc 123
def 456
ghi 789
```

file 2:

```
abc 321
ghi 987
```

I've heard awk is what I need, but how can I use it to make this desired output?

```
abc 321
def 456
ghi 987
```

You can assume all data has been de-duplicated within the files. So the only thing it needs to do is iterate through the files, and if there's a match between files 1 and 2 on column 1, the output should be the information in file 2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to use `join`, especially if your files are already sorted.

Comment: Will there be keys in file2 that are not in file1, or is file2 always a subset of file1?

Comment: If the order of the lines in the output does not matter: `awk '{a[$1]=$0} END{for(i in a) print a[i]}' file1 file2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sort:

```
sort -k1,1 -u file2 file1
```

Output:

```
abc 321
def 456
ghi 987
```

Comment: Why `tac` instead of `cat`?

Comment: @Barmar: Thank you. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: How does this guarantee that it will select the row from file 2 when there's duplication?

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking to do. I'll have to learn awk another day under a less tight deadline. :)

Comment: You need the `--stable` option to prefer the line from the first file.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar! I'll keep that in mind for the future. In this case I always want the line from the second file.

Comment: @R.Senterfeit He put the second file first in the command line. You need `--stable` to prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the keys in file2 are strictly a subset of what appears in file1

```
awk 'NR==FNR {f2[$1] = $2; next} $1 in f2 {$2 = f2[$1]} 1' file2 file1
```